# Why is Inspinia Sidebar Collapse not working?

Tags: html, css, sidebar, inspinia

Following are the codes that I have entered in my dotnet core 3.1 project.

I saw in some examples, navbar-collapse was used, but didn't find it in this template. Yet it seemed to be working fine in the full html version. I am not very good at css/jquery. Can anyone help?

_Navigation.cshtml

```
<nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
            <li class="nav-header">
                <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                    <span class="block m-t-xs font-bold">XYZ</span>
                    <span class="text-muted text-xs block">System Administrator <b class="caret"></b></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs" style="position: absolute; top: 91px; left: 0px; will-change: top, left;">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-element">
                XYZ
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class=@Html.IsSelected("Home")>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="nav-label">Dashboard</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

_TopNavBar.cshtml

```
<div class="row border-bottom">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <li style="padding:20px">
                    <span class="m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message">Welcome @User.Identity.Name</span>
                </li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li style="padding:20px">
                    <span class="m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message">Welcome Guest</span>
                </li>
            }
            <li>
                @*<a asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="SignOut">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
            </a>*@
                <a href="/Identity/LogOut">
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>XYZ</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <!-- Add local styles, mostly for plugins css file -->
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Styles"))
    {@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)}

<environment names="Development">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.css" />
    <link href="~/lib/dualListbox/bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/dataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.css" />
    <link href="~/lib/dualListbox/bootstrap-duallistbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/dataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>


</head>
<body>


    <!-- Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <partial name="_Navigation" />

        <!-- Page wraper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg @ViewBag.SpecialClass">

            <!-- Top Navbar -->
            <partial name="_TopNavbar" />

            <!--Hierarchy Selector-->
            @*<partial name="_HierarchyPartial" />*@

            <!-- Main view  -->
            @RenderBody()

            <!-- Footer -->
            <partial name="_Footer" />

        </div>
        <!-- End page wrapper-->

    </div>
    <!-- End wrapper-->

    <environment names="Production">
        <script src="~/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/Popper/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/metisMenu/dist/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/pace/pace.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/dualListbox/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/plugins/dualListbox/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js"></script>

        <script src="~/datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Only for demo purpose -->
        <script src="~/js/skin.config.js"></script>
        <script src="~/inspinia.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/script.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Development">
        <script src="~/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/Popper/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/metisMenu/dist/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/dualListbox/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/plugins/dualListbox/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

        <script src="~/datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/inspinia.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/script.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, I also have this problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I too have a problem in ReactJS for this.